# Android: Contact list has duplicate names

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I have a contact list in a sort order. But in my contact list the name is duplicating with same number. I think the issue is because of the contact list sync with different account.

I check with Hash map. But when I using hash map the result is not sorted with name .

```
private static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
};

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION,
  null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC");

if (cursor != null) {
    try {
        int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        String nameContact = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
    finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
holder.name.setText(itemListPogo.get(position).getItemName());
```

Can anyone please help to avoid the duplication in name.

Comment: Please post full code adapter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will recommend you to use where my searching ends, it will give you fastest result.

```
public static List<ContactDTO> getPhone(Context context) {
    List<ContactDTO> contactList = new ArrayList<ContactDTO>();
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver(); 
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { 
        ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID, 
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID };

    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String filter = ""+ ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " > 0 and " + Phone.TYPE +"=" + Phone.TYPE_MOBILE;     
    String order = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";// LIMIT " + limit + " offset " + lastId + "";

    Cursor phoneCur = cr.query(uri, PROJECTION, filter, null, order);
    while(phoneCur.moveToNext()) {
        ContactDTO dto = new ContactDTO();
        dto.setName("" + phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        dto.setMobileNo("" + phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
        dto.setPhotoUrl("" + phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI)));
        dto.setContactId("" + phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID)));
        contactList.add(dto);
    }
    phoneCur.close();

    return contactList;
}
```

where ContactDTO is Simple POJO class.

Comment: From from Uri we cannot retrieve the email address.Is their any way to get the name,phone and email in one query.

Answer (score 7):

You're seeing duplicate contacts because they belong to different accounts. i.e. Same number can show up 3 times if it is synced with Facebook, WhatsApp, and Google account. You can find more information here [Android Account Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)

This is how you can use column **ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE** to filter and retrieve contacts associated with a single account only.

```
String[] projection = new String[] {
                    ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID,
                    ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID };


            String selectionFields =  ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = ?";
            String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"com.google"};

            Cursor cursor =  getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,
                    selectionFields,
                    selectionArgs,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
            );
```

In this code, only contacts that are associated with Google Account are selected. Similarly, if you want to get list of WhatsApp Contacts only you can replace **"com.google"** with **"com.whatsapp"**

Comment: That is great @Zain, I am able to filter the google contacts now, do you know how to filter on a specific google account if there is more than one google account on the device?

Answer (score 0):

> I think the issue is because of the contact list sync with different
>   account.

Yes, your contact list sync many account. You should filter contact with Account type : `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ACCOUNT_TYPE_AND_DATA_SET`.
Account you can research in :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the `aggregated` Contact instead of all RawContacts. This will give you only 1 contact with the given name (like in the Contacts app).
Example (changing your code):

```
private static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, // Honeycomb+ should use this
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
};

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(
    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
    PROJECTION, 
    null, 
    null, 
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC");

if (cursor != null) {
    try {
        int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY);
        String nameContact = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
    finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html