# How to add an object to RealmList in Java? Nullpointerexception error

Tags: realm

I am an android developer, previous I had been working with ActiveAndroid and DBFlow but now we are interested in implement Realm Database to our new projects. The problem is that I am getting an error when trying to add an object to a RealmList inside our models. The error is a **Nullpointerexception**.

This is my Country model

```
public class Country extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

@PrimaryKey
private int id;

private String name;
private RealmList<Region> regions;

public Country() {
}

public Country(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
getter and setters...
```

And this is my Region model

```
public class Region extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

@PrimaryKey
private int id;

private String name;

private int countryId;

public RealmList<City> cities;

public Region() {
}

public Region(int id, String name, int countryId ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.countryId = countryId;
}
getter and setters...
```

The main method where I am trying to save the data is

```
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
        Country country=new Country();
        country.setId(i);
        country.setName("testCountryName " + i);

        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            Region region=new Region();
            region.setId(y);
            region.setName("testRegionName " + y);

            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(region);
            country.regions.add(region);
        }

        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(country);
    }
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

Finally, the only way to avoid the Nullpointerexception error is adding `= new RealmList<>();` when I am declaring the RealmList in each model.

I don't find this answer at Realm Docs and the samples never say that I need to initialize the RealmList so, for that reason I am looking for a solution here.

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: What version of Realm are you using? I advise 1.2.0

Comment: Hi, I am using 1.2.0. -> "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're creating unmanaged RealmObjects that are essentially vanilla objects right here:

```
Country country = new Country();

Region region = new Region();
```

With that in mind, there's no magic here, that list in `country.regions` was never initialized by anyone :)

So you'd need this:

```
country.setRegions(new RealmList<Region>());
region.setCities(new RealmList<City>());
```

You can avoid this manual creation of lists (if I'm right, anyways) if you create managed copies in the Realm immediately using `realm.createObject(__.class, primaryKeyValue);`.

Like

```
Country country = realm.createObject(Country.class, i);
```

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce, I didn't know that I can set my own primaryKeyValue at **createObject** method. I will try your solution and give you a feedback.

Comment: Technically, not setting it in `createObject()` on an object that has a `@PrimaryKey` field will soon become deprecated :)

Comment: if i use this `Country country = realm.createObject(Country.class, i);` I am getting this error `io.realm.exceptions.RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already exists: 0`. is also necessary to add this `country.setRegions(new RealmList<Region>());
region.setCities(new RealmList<City>());`?. Could you help me?

Comment: I would assume it's because the country already exists with primary key value 0

Comment: I don't have a value in the db. :s I mean, is the first time that I execute the app.

Comment: I think this might actually be a bug specific to having an item with the ID value `0`, considering [it's supposed to work](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#createObject-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-). You could verify that by calling `i+1` as ID instead of `i`. Personally I tend to go with the detached object route and then I insert the element ([here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352489/how-to-read-contacts-in-android-using-realm/39352718#39352718))